# Using Multiple Values in MVC Controller parameter.string.contains

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Code I have:

```
    public ViewResult Index(string tech)
    {
        var queue = db.Table1.Where(t => t.TECHID == tech).ToList();

        queue = queue.Where(t => t.STAT.Contains("90I")).ToList();

        return View(queue);
    }
```

This effectively gets me all lines where STAT == 90I and TECHID is equal to whoever is logged in.  How do I reverse this so that I get all records NOT Containing 90I, and is there a way for me to make it not get 90I AND not get 00C, or get all records where STAT is between (inclusive) 10E and 70C?

Value examples:  00C, 10E, 45I, 60A, 65B, 65O, 65P, 66A, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make negation, you need change your condition into negation:

```
queue = queue.Where(t => !t.STAT.Contains("90I")).ToList();
```

Not 90I and not 00C:

```
queue = queue.Where(t => !t.STAT.Contains("90I") && !t.STAT.Contains("00C")).ToList();
```

What do you mean by "between"??

Comment: The negation is where I was heading with all that... I think.  I wasn't sure how to "Not" it.  What I had meant by between is all the codes are numerically sequential (00C comes before 10E, etc.)  I wasn't sure if there was a way to say equal or greater than 10E and less than or equal to 70C.  What you offered will get me where I need to go, I may have to make it unseemly (not this and not that and not them too) but I can get there from here.  Thank you!